# Android get every file in a folder

Tags: java, android, file, directory

Let's say I have the folder "/sdcard/my_pictures" and it has a bunch of images in it, `img1.png`, `img2.png`, ..., `img3.png`.

What is the correct syntax to iterate through these? I want something of the form:

```
Folder folder = new Folder(folder_path_string);
for (File file : folder) {
    //do stuff with the file
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used the following loop for my project with ***JDK 1.6***.

```
File[] files = new File("folder_path_string").listFiles();
for (File f:files) {
    //operate..
}
```

Tested on ***Android*** with the following lines and got the right output.

```
File[] files = new File("//sdcard//").listFiles();
String fileNames = "";
for(File f:files){
    fileNames += f.getName() + " - ";
}
textEdit.setText(fileNames);
```

Comment: Was looking for this solution for one of my projects as well.

Comment: I have a slow computer, I cannot start the emulator, I keep trying. you can try yourself, too.

Comment: Perhaps I'm doing something wrong with my Android file path, I get a null pointer exception on for(File f:files) line. I have a folder called "clay_models" and I've created it in the top level hierarchy of the other folders (e.g. 'Android', 'DCIM', 'Download', ...). I've tried '/sdcard/clay_models/' as well as '//sdcard/clay_models' and also with sdcard//. Thoughts?

Comment: //sdcard//clay_models// all "/"s should be "//"